# Angular does not update after emptying array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, angularfire

I have the following HTML where the first line shows the :

```
<p>{{cal.eventSources}}</p>
<div ui-calendar ng-model="cal.eventSources"></div>
```

In my JS I have:

```
    $scope.$apply(setupCalendarEvents());

    function setupCalendarEvents(){

      self.eventSources = []; 

      angular.forEach(bookingMap, function(value, key) {
        self.eventSources.push(bookingMap[key]);
      });

    }
```

**Problem:** Why does the first HTML line updates but the events do not come into the calendar?

**More info**

If I remove the `self.eventSources = [];` line then the events do come in the calendar but each obviously time I add an event all the prior events are duplicated.

If I remove the `$scope.$apply()` then nothing updates.

I am using [ui.calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/)

Comment: Did you try with just `$scope.$apply(setupCalendarEvents);` or putting `$scope.$apply();` at the bottom inside your function? How does this function get called the subsequent times?

Comment: Neither one works. I use FireBase. Each time something is added to the database, `bookingMap` is updated and the function is ran again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the following line of code severs the connection between the calendar and the model because it creates a  new array:

```
self.eventSources = [];
```

Instead I replaced the line with:

```
self.eventSources.length = 0;
```

And i all works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, avoid $scope.$apply. I don't why everyone keeps posting examples with it. When you code properly, there's almost no use case for $scope.$apply. If you need it, chances are your data binding is not done properly.

Comment: This is actually a case where I need it because the data is not there on the first pass and Angular has no way to know I changed the model unless I tell it...